# Loading data on different cases

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following implementation. As you see I am trying to load the data with network operation on three different cases :

- `viewDidLoad`
- `applicationEnteredForeground`
- `pushNotificationMessageReceived`

I wonder whether not I am doing more than required in the following class with calling network operation in three different places.

Are there something could be redundant or any advice or suggestion?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadData];    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(pushNotificationMessageReceived:)
                                                     name:@"restaurantOrderNotificationMessage"
                                                   object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationIsActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationEnteredForeground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationEnteredForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Application Entered Foreground");
    [self loadData];
}

- (void)applicationIsActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Application Did Become Active");
}

// AppDelegate notification center calls
-(void)pushNotificationMessageReceived: (NSNotification *)notification{

    [self loadData];
}
```

Comment: If you have three different triggers to fetch data from the network, then that is what you need to do.

Comment: @PaulW11, should I still need to loadData in `viewDidLoad` method since there is an `applicationEnteredForeground` notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called when the `UIView` is loaded. Therefore, it is only called once when the view is loaded initially.

`applicationEnteredForeground` is called once when the App is summoned from the background. When the App goes back to background (user pressed Home button, or switched to other app) then go back to your App, this notification will be triggered again.

In your case, you might want to put your network function call in both `viewDidLoad` and `applicationEnteredForeground` just like you did. For `pushNotificationMessageReceived`, you should handle it separately. There are 2 possible cases, at least:

1. **The push notification is received when your App is active**: you might consider to handle the push notification message as an alert. You only load data when your user clicks OK in your alert, as you might give them a choice not to load the data (depending on your user experience design)
2. **The push notification is received when your App is in background**: when the user clicks the notification banner / alert, the App will launch, and the `applicationEnteredForeground` will be called. Therefore, there is no need to add `loadData` in this case.

Please let me know if you're still unclear.